# Work sizes for completely independent calculations in OpenCL

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, gpgpu

I have a 2D matrix where I want to modify every value by applying a function that is only dependent on the coordinates in the matrix and values set at compile-time. Since no synchronization is necessary between each such calculation, it seems to me like the work group size could really be 1, and the number of work groups equal to the number of elements in the matrix.

My question is whether this will actually yield the desired result, or whether other forces are at play here that might make a different setting for these values better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recomendation: Just set global size to your 2D matrix size, and local size to NULL. This will make the compiler select for you an optimal local size.

In your specific case, the local size does not need to hav any shape. In fact, any value value will do the work, but the performance may differ. You can tune it manually for different HW. But it is easyer to let the compiler do this job for you. And it is even more portable.

Comment: Hmm, what effect will this have on get_global_id vs get_local_id to get the coordinates in the overall matrix?

Comment: You can use them as always. get_global_id() will always return the global id. Regardless the local size. And get_local_id() will return the local id, which depends on the local size selected by the compiler. In that case you can use get_local_size() to get the local size used at run time. However, you stated that your work items do not need local sync, so this is not needed at all.